# Hardops + Blender 2.9 Support

Tags: add-on

https://gumroad.com/l/hardops

Can anyone confirm if the HardOps (2.8) addon is compatible with Blender 2.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of HardOps (00986_MercuryX_24) works with Blender 2.9. You might have to restart Blender before it starts working.

[image]